# Search for mails with text containing special character in Outlook Inbox

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2016

I need to find all the mails, in my MS Outlook 2016 Inbox , that contain 6% in the body of the mail.
When I search (Advanced Search too) all the mails that contain the digit 6 are given in result ignoring the %.

Pl help on this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, if the word starts or ends with a special character, then Instant Search will ignore this special character as the index of Instant Search is word-based only. 
However, if the special character is within the word such as mso#123 then you can search for this exact string by placing it between quotes "mso#123".

To search for a word which starts or ends with a special character, we can use Advanced search feature.

To do this, click Search Tools under Search tab and choose Advanced Find. Under Advanced, set following criteria.

[image]

If you want to search items containing the exact phrase 6% and not the variations such as 86% or 6%6, we can use quotation marks. For example: “6%”

[image]